# Should you manually add a css file in a gulp project?

Tags: dependency-injection, gulp, bower, gulp-sass

I have tried so many times to get skeleton.css in the **index.html** for my gulp-angular project but still can't find a way to. I used bower install to install skeleton-css and it added it into its respective folder in the **bower-component** folder

I have tried adding it manually to **index.html** in the **.tmp** folder but whenever I do `gulp serve`, whatever code i added disappears:

Before running `gulp serve`

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/skeleton.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

After running `gulp serve`

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I know this pretty much a nooby question and it has to do with the way injection works in gulp but I can't seem to understand it as i'm quite new to the task automation environment, any ideas where I might be going wrong and any solutions ?

Thanks so much!

**Gulp Task**

```
gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([
    paths.tmp + '/serve',
    paths.src
  ], [
    paths.tmp + '/serve/{app,components}/**/*.css',
    paths.tmp + '/serve/{app,components}/**/*.js',
    paths.src + 'src/assets/images/**/*',
    paths.tmp + '/serve/*.html',
    paths.tmp + '/serve/{app,components}/**/*.html',
    paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.html'
  ]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([paths.tmp + '/serve', paths.src], null, []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(paths.dist, null, []);
});
```

Comment: Share your gulp tasks

Comment: @entre, I have just Updated the question !

Comment: Iis that code incomplete, I don't see gulp inject anywhere